# Can i avoid queuing if maxConCurrentInstances are crossed in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

My requirement is as below:
Service shall serve only one client. If additional client tries to give call service, it shall notify client with with error/exception (or errorCode).

MaxConCurrentInstances can limit number of requests at a time but it I don't want to queue request from additional client. I simply want to terminate that request with exception or error?

Is it possible to achieve with MaxConCurrentInstances or do i need to use anything else?

Thanks in advance,
Ujjwal

Comment: why not create singleton instance of service? then it *will* serve only one client at the time

Comment: I don't think making service singleton will limit number of clients. It will only make sure that same instance of service shall shared among different calls (or clients)(Correct me if i am wrong in my understanding here). If you combine this with Concurrency.Single, it will serve one request at a time. What i want achieve is kind of mapping. Once one client is connected to the service, no other client shall be able to access service till first get disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having two methods - *gateway* method, that will set a flag and enter the *real* method, do work for the first user and throw an exception / return false for other users while the flag is on? Then, when the real method finishes, it puts down the flag and another "first" user can consume the method?

Comment: Yes, i think, i have to go ahead with this approach only. Ideally, i wanted to achieve this using WCF's features but right now, none seems to be suitable for the requirement.

Comment: good to hear. if the answer helped you, mark it as correct then, please